# How to finish this Java classes assignment?

Tags: java

Here is my assignment:

> 1. Create a class that contains an address book entry and name it AddressBook. The table below describes the information that an address book entry has. Name, Address, Mobile Number, Email Address.

Here is my code, I am not sure if it's correct:

```
public class AddressBook {
   private String name;
   private String address;
   private int mobilenumber;
   private String emailaddress;

   public AddressBook(){}

   public AddressBook (String name, String address, 
                       int mobilenumber, String emailaddress){
       this.name = name;
       this.address = address;
       this.mobilenumber = mobilenumber;
       this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
   }

    public String getName(){ 
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){ 
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress(){ 
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address){ 
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getMobileNumber(){ 
        return mobilenumber;
    }
    public void setMobileNumber(int mobilenumber){
        this.mobilenumber = mobilenumber;}

    public String getEmailAddress(){
        return emailaddress;
    }
    public void setEmailAddress(String emailaddress){ 
        this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
    }

     public String toString(){
         return "Name: " + name + "Address: " + address +
         "Mobile Number: " + mobilenumber + "Email Address: " + emailaddress;        
         }
}
```

Here is the next part of the assignment:

> 2. Create a class and name it AddressBookTest which will contain the main method for implementation of the AddressBook class methods from #1 of this activity.  Instantiate an array of AddressBook objects of 100 entries.  Create a menu that will implement the following methods:
>
> Main Menu
>
> 1. Add Entry
> 2. Delete Entry
> 3. View All Entries
> 4. Update An Entry
> 5. Exit
>
> The program should loop back to the main menu after implementing a method chosen by the user. Note that options 2, 3 and 4 should not be implemented if no entry has been added yet. The program ends at the Exit option.

Here my current code, I don't know how to delete, view all or update?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AddressBookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("***PROGRAM INFORMATION*** \nNAME
                           ->  IS THE NAME OF THE PERSON IN THE ADDRESSBOOK \nADDRESS
                           ->  THE ADDRESS OF THE PERSON \nMOBILE NUMBER
                           ->  THE MOBILE NUMBER OF THE PERSON \nEMAIL ADDRESS   
                           ->  THE EMAIL ADDRESS OF THE PERSON\n");

        String input;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        AddressBook[] entry = new AddressBook[100];

        do
        {

            System.out.println("Main Menu");  
            System.out.println("1. Add an Entry");
            System.out.println("2. Delete an Entry");
            System.out.println("3. View All Entries");
            System.out.println("4. Update an Entry");
            System.out.println("5. Exit");
            System.out.print("Please enter Choices from 1 to 5: "); 
            input =(in.nextLine());



            switch (input) {
                case "1":

                    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                    entry[i] = new AddressBook();

                    System.out.println("***Adding Entry in Address Book***");
                    System.out.print("First Name: ");
                    String name = in.next();
                    System.out.print("Address: ");
                    String address = in.next();
                    System.out.print("Mobile Number: ");
                    int MN = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Email Address: ");
                    String EA = in.next();
                    System.out.println("***Added " + (i+1) + " Entry/Entries\n");

                    }
                    break;

                case "2":

                    break;

                case "3":


                    break;
                case "4":

                     break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }while(!input.equals("5"));
            System.out.println("***THANK YOU FOR USING MY PROGRAM...***");
    }      
}
```

Comment: Good, you have learn how to write a program in Java. Please consider to learn 
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  as well.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question in the above.

Comment: Your `AdressBook` is fine, but it's an `AddressBookEntry`. You need to also write a proper `AddressBook` that maintains a list of those entries, with the appropriate methods for add/delete etc.

Comment: There are other sections for code review

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this answer helps you with your question:

> Here my current code, I don't know how to delete, view all or update?

I really tried to keep it basic, the only new thing introduced is the list instead of an array.

Well first things first, like already said by @daniu. We'll need to change AddressBook to AddressBookEntry, because it really is an entry, not an address book.

AddressBookEntry.java:

```
package com.kaufland;

//class like it was given
public class AddressBookEntry {

private String name;
private String address;
private int mobilenumber;
private String emailaddress;

public AddressBookEntry() {}

public AddressBookEntry(String name, String address,
                        int mobilenumber, String emailaddress){
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.mobilenumber = mobilenumber;
        this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
        }

public String getName(){
        return name;
        }
public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
        }

public String getAddress(){
        return address;
        }
public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address = address;
        }

public int getMobileNumber(){
        return mobilenumber;
        }
public void setMobileNumber(int mobilenumber){
        this.mobilenumber = mobilenumber;}

public String getEmailAddress(){
        return emailaddress;
        }
public void setEmailAddress(String emailaddress){
        this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
        }

public String toString(){
        return "Name: " + name + ", Address: " + address +
        ", Mobile Number: " + mobilenumber + ", Email Address: " + emailaddress;
        }
}
```

Second we need class which represents our AddressBook and contains a List of AddressBookEntries. We chose a List here, because it is easy to extend, which a AdressBook should be.

AdressBook.java:

```
package com.kaufland;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AddressBook {

//The diamond operators "<" and ">" specify which type of Objects the List will hold
private List<AddressBookEntry> listOfEntries;

public AddressBook() {
    //initialize list of entries
    this.listOfEntries = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void add(AddressBookEntry addressBookEntry) {
    //List.add adds a new Object to a List
    this.listOfEntries.add(addressBookEntry);
}

public void delete(int index) {
    //List.remove(int index) removes a object at the given index
    this.listOfEntries.remove(index);
}

public AddressBookEntry get(int index) {
    //List.get(int index) returns the object at the given index
    return this.listOfEntries.get(index);
}

public AddressBookEntry[] viewAll() {
    //create a new array with the size of our list
    AddressBookEntry[] result = new AddressBookEntry[this.listOfEntries.size()];

    //List.toArray(Arr[] array) fills our array with data from the list
    this.listOfEntries.toArray(result);

    //return the filled array
    return result;
}
}
```

Last we need to apply some changes to your AddressBookTest class, so that we use the functions of our new created AddressBook!

AddressBookTest.java:

```
package com.kaufland;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class AddressBookTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("***PROGRAM INFORMATION*** \nNAME" +
            "->  IS THE NAME OF THE PERSON IN THE ADDRESSBOOK \nADDRESS" +
            "->  THE ADDRESS OF THE PERSON \nMOBILE NUMBER" +
            "->  THE MOBILE NUMBER OF THE PERSON \nEMAIL ADDRESS" +
            "->  THE EMAIL ADDRESS OF THE PERSON\n");

    String input;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    AddressBook addressBook = new AddressBook();

    boolean stop = false;
    do
    {

        System.out.println("\nMain Menu");
        System.out.println("1. Add an Entry");
        System.out.println("2. Delete an Entry");
        System.out.println("3. View All Entries");
        System.out.println("4. Update an Entry");
        System.out.println("5. Exit");
        System.out.print("Please enter Choices from 1 to 5: \n");
        input =(in.next());



        switch (input) {
            case "1":
                //create a new entry for the addressbook
                AddressBookEntry entry = new AddressBookEntry();

                System.out.println("***Adding Entry in Address Book***");

                System.out.print("First Name: ");
                entry.setName(in.next());

                System.out.print("Address: ");
                entry.setAddress(in.next());

                System.out.print("Mobile Number: ");
                entry.setMobileNumber(in.nextInt());

                System.out.print("Email Address: ");
                entry.setEmailAddress(in.next());

                //add our new entry to the addressbook
                addressBook.add(entry);

                System.out.println("Added a new entry.");
                break;

            case "2":
                System.out.println("Enter the index of the entry, which you want to delete:");
                //delete the entry at the given index
                addressBook.delete(in.nextInt());

                break;

            case "3":
                System.out.println("Your addressbook contains the following entries:");
                //get array of all entries
                AddressBookEntry[] listOfEntries = addressBook.viewAll();

                //for every entry in the array
                for (int i = 0; i < listOfEntries.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(listOfEntries[i].toString());
                }

                break;
            case "4":
                System.out.println("Enter the index of the entry, which you want to update:");
                //get entry at the given index
                AddressBookEntry entryToUpdate = addressBook.get(in.nextInt());

                System.out.print("First Name (current: " + entryToUpdate.getName() + "):");
                entryToUpdate.setName(in.next());

                System.out.print("Address: (current: " + entryToUpdate.getAddress() + "):");
                entryToUpdate.setAddress(in.next());

                System.out.print("Mobile Number: (current: " + entryToUpdate.getMobileNumber() + "):");
                entryToUpdate.setMobileNumber(in.nextInt());

                System.out.print("Email Address: (current: " + entryToUpdate.getEmailAddress() + "):");
                entryToUpdate.setEmailAddress(in.next());

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    //execute while stop is false
    } while (!input.equals("5"));
    System.out.println("***THANK YOU FOR USING MY PROGRAM...***");
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help, I will study this,,,,,really help me a lot now is working.........

Comment: Niklas now the program is not working because as per my assignment I have to make addressbook.java then my runner addressbooktest. java where there a method  I can add, delete, update then the exit I tried to combine your code in addressbook and addressbook test however there are some errors I tried to change but still not working...can you help me again

Comment: I have upvoted this somewhat reluctantly. The question is obviously too broad for the Stack Overflow platform, and I am cautious about rewarding answers to such questions, when we should be encouraging question authors to ask a focussed and well-researched question first. Nevertheless, it looks very helpful, well done.

Comment: (It is my experience that questions of this kind are shortly followed up by comments of the "it doesn't work" variety, because (again) insufficient effort has been expended on getting your answer working (as has happened in this case). It is up to you how much you respond to such comments, but bear in mind you will end up working for free if you are not careful, and you may even not get acceptances and upvotes from such posters, since they often abandon the platform as soon as things are working on their machine).

Comment: @ProgramBeginner90 If I am guessing right, your project requires a different structure then the one I supposed to you. You can not simply copy/paste my code then, but that wasnt the purpose of it anyway. Just create a new Project with the three files like I called them, test it, read into it and you will find a way to put the source code in a way, which is acceptable for your assignment.

Comment: @halfer I'm aware of the risk of not getting acceptance or upvotes, I just had some sparetime and nothing to do :D